# Decode a column of Base64 strings in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, base64

**Situation:** I have a column that I'll be extracting from SQL with hundreds of thousands of Base 64 strings that I would like to decode.

One decoded string looks like this:

```
b'{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,...}'
```

**Objective:**
How can I simply extract the value of the first dictionary. In this case, this would be 1. I would like the results to end up in a `numpy` array or df.

I found the following code to help me decode one string but unsure how to use it for every row in a column.

```
import base64
coded_string = '''value to decode'''
base64.b64decode(coded_string)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: Turn it into an object and access it like you would a dictionary.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  get the following error message when parsing ValueError: malformed node or string:

Comment: That's because you're passing a byte object, you need to decode it first: `result = ast.literal_eval(entry.decode('utf8'))`

Comment: sure if you dont mind post the answer so i can accept it as solved @TheIncorrigible1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your snippet is well-formed Python (although, this seems more likely to be JSON), you can use `literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from base64 import b64decode
from pprint import pprint

binary = b64decode(some_str)

lib = literal_eval(binary.decode('utf8'))
pprint(lib)
```